# Retrieve array value by index

Tags: php

If I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_path] => 3blocks-02.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_path] => 2blocks-02.png
        )
)
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the ['image_path'] value by the array index in a forreach loop?

I have tried:

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
   $image[1]
}

and 

foreach($images as $image)
{
   $image[1]['image_path']
}
```

and a key => value loop but I cant seem to get the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$image_paths = array_column($your_array,'image_path');
print_r($image_paths);
```

Here is the link of [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Can i use that in a loop? I have tried `foreach($image_paths as $image){$image[0]}` but I still don't get anything

Comment: No need to use loop at all just below your array, Try once above code for your array, you will get what you need, trust me

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
   echo $image['image_path'];
}
```

or

```
echo $images[0]['image_path'];
```

Comment: Explain your code. Code only answers are bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$array = Array(
          Array(image_path => '3blocks-02.png'),
          Array(image_path => '2blocks-02.png')
);


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  print_r($value['image_path']); 
}
```

working example - http://codepad.org/i0B5X8lW